# Migrate Visual Studio 2012 Solutions to Another Server NOT Version

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Actually quite a simple issue. I have been using a slow laptop to develop on VS2012, and I setup a screamer to develop on now. No change in versions, etc., just doing it all on a different machine.

To be honest, I haven't even copied the *Projects* folder yet, as I'm not sure if there wold be project-specific options that would be reset/broken.

To be clear, the new 2012 is Ultimate, and I haven't even tried to migrate. There have been a LOT of options/features added to my existing projects & solutions, so it may not be as simple as copy/paste the *Projects* folder.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Visual Studio, like most other IDEs, is built to allow large teams to work on the same projects. Copying projects works. Project specific options are stored in the project file, which you can look at with a text editor. Some projects may reference libraries that are not installed on the new machine - just install them and you're done.

Comment: But you'll still want to export your VS settings from your old VS2012 install and import them into the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peter and @JohnnyHK,

You both were right. I was putting this off on a new machine for fear that I'd need to remember a ton of things I hadn't documented in the Solution (and projects under it-about 20).

So I was already using subversion on the old machine, so I added VisualSVN/Tortoise and checked out a copy of the solution to the new Projects folder. There were like 350 errors & more warnings! Yikes!

But I went through them very quickly and it is clean now. One thing that I noticed in the process was that VS2012 is a little 'broken' when it comes to project (on-web) references. NuGet was actually amazing in that as soon as I fired up the Package Console, it went along, finding & installing all the packages & dependencies! :)

I enabled Show All Files, then opened the References tree node, and noted the ones with little yellow "X"s next to them. In the good side, ones that were not needed (I added them, but created just clutter) were good to see & delete. BUT, there were mostly errors from references that had references to DLLs that were actually in the right place, and when I left clicked on the reference with the error icon, the error would simply go away. Weird, but preferable...

The strangest ones were reference to DLLs that were where they were supposed to be (I'd make a .\lib directory in the project, a la *NIX style, and throw all DLLs for that project in there), BUT I had to delete the reference in error (even though the project was pointing to the right file/location) and then re-browse for it, adding it again, and all errors went away.

All in all, I was pretty impressed with the ease-even with the weirdness-it went. Once I saw how the references were broken, I just went into each project & treated each one. Let me be clear for anyone doing a mass WPF migration: If I had started with the first project and worked to the end one, and ONLY fixed the References issues, I would have been done in 5 minutes-includes time for NuGet to auto-load.

I will not lie; This was the first big migration of a solution to a new machine, and when I saw like 700 warnings/errors, I thought "There goes another weekend!", but I will warn those in this situation to NOT go into source code and try to fix each red underline. You will break things!